# Expanding Bootstrap navbar menu not working at breakpoint

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm new to HTML/CSS Im currently playing around with Bootstrap, I am using the navbar component.

I've moved some stuff around, alignment of text, and added a logo, but when I reduce the size of the screen and hit the breakpoint in which the burger icon should appear for the menu to be dropdown, it does not show, it's there to be clicked but does not work.

I've added in all libraries etc but still no joy, I've placed my code below. Again I'm new to coding so any help is very much appreciated.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="LogoIcon"><img src="G_icon.png" alt="" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">GRAFT</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">CONTACT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my pc.

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet, referable minimsed to show just enough code to demonstrate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make sure the snippet does show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you.
It's responsive Navbar and working in all the devices.

Please refer this link for Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/byngdzqt/

ALAP
        
          
        
        
          
            
              Home
            
            
              About
            
            
              Work
            
          
          CONTACT

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#" class="LogoIcon"><img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/80/3888/2592.jpg?hmac=zD95NwXZ7mGAMj-z4444Elf43I4HJvd7Afm2tloweLw" alt="Logo" width="50px" height="50px" class="rounded"/></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mx-3" href="#">ALAP</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end align-items-center;" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav w-25 justify-content-evenly ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">CONTACT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers can be made more useful if accompanied by a verbal explanation of what has been changed and why.

Comment: It was working fine but there would be a caching issue. So I've made it more readable for easy to understand.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is a misunderstanding. I meant please explain what is different between your code and the code given in the question and why that has made a difference in the outcome.

Comment: @AlapJoshi can you tell me which part from the original code did you fix in order for it to work correctly?